# Swift 3 webView local HTML

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I need to load local HTML, CSS and JS into an iOS app to make my boss happy. I'm using Xcode 8.3.1 and Swift 3. I have created a new project with a WebView placed in my Main.storyboard

Other StackOverflow resources helped me get this far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let urlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html");
    let requesturl = URL(string: urlpath!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: requesturl!)
    webView.mainFrame.load(request)
}
```

I get this error:

> Value of type 'UIWebView' has no member 'mainFrame'

When I remove `mainFrame` it says I'm missing a mimeType. Can anyone help? I'm obviously a noob to Swift.

Comment: `webView.loadRequest(request)` instead? Using `func loadRequest(_ request: URLRequest)` (doc: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617957-loadrequest)

Comment: Yes thank you so much, how do I vote you up or send props? Ive read 1000s of questions but never posted one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mainFrame` is from the class `WebView` which is only for macOS.

Since you are using `UIWebView`, you need to use `webView.loadRequest`.

You also have a problem with your URL. Either use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` to create the `URL` from the path string or, better yet, use `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)` and get the `URL` directly.

You might also want to use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`. It has a lot more features and it may be more useful for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "temp", ofType: "html")!
    //reading
    var text = try! String.init(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "${contents}", with: contents)
    // load string
    let bundleURL = URL.init(string: path)
    webView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: bundleURL)
```

done!